# Is this a bug or am I missing something? (Casting UISplitViewController)

Tags: ios, swift, uisplitviewcontroller

```
class DocumentNavigationController: UINavigationController {
    public var documentSplitViewController: DocumentSplitViewController? {
        return splitViewController as? DocumentSplitViewController
    }
}
```

Accessing it in a subclass that also implements UISplitViewControllerDelegate.

```
func primaryViewController(forExpanding splitViewController: UISplitViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    ...
    print("Before:  Split- \(splitViewController) DocSplit- \(documentSplitViewController)")
    if let docSplit = splitViewController as? DocumentSplitViewController {
        print("Cast successful")
    } else { print("Cast failed")}
    print("After:  Split- \(splitViewController) DocSplit- \(documentSplitViewController)")
    ...
}
```

**Output:**

```
Before:  Split- <PDF_Express.DocumentSplitViewController: 0x7fcf9050fc60> DocSplit- nil

Cast successful

After:  Split- <PDF_Express.DocumentSplitViewController: 0x7fcf9050fc60> DocSplit- nil
```

My expected results would be that DocSplit is not nil in the print statements.   I don't understand why the function is not properly casting, but my local optional binding is.

Comment: What is the source of your confusion? Are you wondering why nothing has changed after the if?

Comment: @vacawama I expect the functional cast to work the same as the optional binding.  But I get nil returned from the function.

Comment: In `primaryViewController` the `splitViewController` referred to is the one passed into the method where as the `documentSplitViewController` refers to the property of the class.  I would guess they are not actually the same thing.

Comment: Add the same print statement in `documentSplitViewController`.

Comment: @vacawama I can't print documentSplitViewController in it's setter, but I was able to log splitViewController there.  And it is nil and the cast fails. I don't understand why though.

Comment: @UpholderOfTruth Yup that was it.  I was accessing splitViewController, not self.splitViewController.   If you submit  as an answer I'll accept it.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `primaryViewController` the `splitViewController` referred to is the one passed into the method where as the `documentSplitViewController` refers to the property of the class. I would guess they are not actually the same thing.